# How to populate without using ref in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I was doing NodeJS project which is using 2 database

1. Assosiates
2. outlets

Now I want to execute one query which uses populate and in my database I didn't use any "ref" relation

Is there any way to execute query using populate method without changing my database schema?

This is my associate schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;


var  AssociateSchema = new Schema({    
  category_id:{type: ObjectId, max: 100},
  associate_name: {type:String,max: 100},
  associate_address: {type:String,max: 500},
  associate_no: {type:Number},
  associate_emaiid: {type:String,max: 100},
  associate_status: {type:Boolean},
});
    
Associate= mongoose.model('Associate', AssociateSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Associate', AssociateSchema);
```

This is my outlet schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var  OutletSchema = new Schema({    
  associate_id:{type:ObjectId, max: 100},
  outlet_name: {type:String,max: 100},
  outlet_address: {type:String,max: 500},
  outlet_no: {type:Number},
  outlet_status: {type:Boolean},
  city_id:{type:ObjectId, max: 100},
});
    
module.exports = mongoose.model('Outlet', OutletSchema);
```

This is the query I am using:

```
router.get('/getma', function (req, res) {
  Associate.findOne({ _id: '' })
    .populate('outlets')
    .exec(function (err,dea) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(dea)
      res.json(dea)
    })
});
```

Comment: You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation to populate outlet in associates model or vice versa

Comment: where to define $lookup, in model or router?

Comment: You do not need to define``lookup` anywhere... It is just an aggregation query just like sql join to connect multiple schema's within a query... Generally It makes the a left outer join like sql...